# Using Razor in Sharepoint Online MVC provider hosted apps?

Tags: sharepoint-online, mvc, chart

Mostly for the purpose of making good looking charts. Is that possible? If so, could someone provide some insight into how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the provider hosted app renders "valid" HTML, you're good to go. Technology, platform, or whatever that produces the HTML on server side is not relevant.

Comment: Thank you. So you'd just add a new razor mvc page to your web project when writing a SPonline app or how would you acomplish that?